# How to access rows and columns of excel file in java

Tags: java

Importing and exporting of excel file

```
   import java.io.File; 
   import java.io.FileInputStream; import
   java.io.FileNotFoundException; 
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException; import
   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell; import
   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow; import
   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet; import
   org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

   public class ExcelRead {

       public static void first() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
           // import of workbok//
           File fs = new File("D:\\Input.xlsx");
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fs);
           XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
           XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

           int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;
           int colnum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
           String[][] data = new String[rownum][colnum];

           for (int i = 0; i < rownum; i++) {
               XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

               for (int j = 0; j < colnum; j++) {
                   XSSFCell Cell = row.getCell(j);
                   data[i][j] = Cell.toString();

                   System.out.print(data[i][j] + "\t\t");
               }
               System.out.println("\t");
               System.out.println("\t\t");
           }
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/NewExcelFile.xlsx");
           workbook.write(fileOut);
           fileOut.close();
           System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
       }

       public static String CellToString() {
           XSSFCell cell = null;
           int type;
           Object result;
           type = cell.getCellType();
           switch (type) {
               case 0:
                   result = cell.getNumericCellValue();
                   break;

               case 1:
                   result = cell.getStringCellValue();
                   break;

               default:
           throw new RuntimeException("There are no support for this type of cell");
           }
           return result.toString();
       } 
}
```

Comment: Please format the code properly

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("path to xlsx file"));
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
{
Row row = rowIterator.next();
Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
{
Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
}
}
```